# Select from a data frame a set of columns that meet a criteria

Tags: r, subset

I would like to know of a command to select columns based on some criteria. For example, suppose I had an N+5 column data frame (where N is arbitrary/unknown) like so:

```
>mydf
Name  Meta1 Meta2 ... MetaN A B C D
Alice a1    a2    ... aN    1 0 1 0 
Bob   b1    b2    ... bN    2 1 2 1
```

I would like to obtain the data frame below by using the fact that the column means of A and C are greater than 1 (or equivalently that the column means of B and D are less than 1).

```
>mydf
Name  Meta1 Meta2 ... MetaN A C
Alice a1    a2    ... aN    1 1 
Bob   b1    b2    ... bN    2 2
```

I have tried combining the subset command's "select" option with logical operations and the colMeans command to no avail. The closest I have gotten to getting this right in general is monstrously complex. I've tried looking for commands that can do this elegantly but haven't yet found any.

EDIT: The column names "Meta1" through "MetaN" should be thought of as place holders and not necessarily the actual names of the columns. They could for all intent and purposes be N random color names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this works:

```
drop <- names(which(colMeans(mydf[-c(1, N+1)])<1))
mydf[!(colnames(mydf) %in% drop)]
```

The nice thing about this is that if in the data frame we had "Meta1" through "MetaN" replaced with names of N random colors like "Blue", "Indigo",... "Mustard" (resp.) this would still work. Even if the number of colors N is unknown but we know the last one is "Mustard", we just need to make a small modification. In the example using colors, we would just change "drop" to this,

```
drop <- names(which(colMeans(mydf[-c(1, which(colnames(mydf)=="Mustard")])<1))
```

and yield the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

There are several straightforward approaches. You can make use of the `colMeans` function here. This assumes your `data.frame` is called "mydf".

```
> mydf[c("Name", names(which(colMeans(mydf[-1]) > 1)))]
   Name A C
1 Alice 1 1
2   Bob 2 2
```

Comment: +1 - Variation on a theme: `data.frame(mydf[1], mydf[-1][colMeans(mydf[-1]) > 1] )`

Comment: Hey Ananda, I've tried to adapt your answer to my actual problem but have hit a wall. I've edited my question so that its slightly generalized and better reflects my issue.

Comment: Make the simple change (where `N` is the your `Nth` column)
`mydf[c("Name", names(which(colMeans(mydf[-c(1:N)]) > 1)))]`

Comment: @Metrics I think you mean N+1 in the code. Either way, that method will only omit columns 1 through N+1 for the colMeans computation which is good, but The final output would also leave out columns Meta1 to MetaN which I want to keep in.

Comment: I see. Here is the solution for that :
`mydf[c("Name",paste("Meta",1:N,sep=""),names(which(colMeans(mydf[-c(1:N)]) > 1)))]`